# How to make MySQL view in drupal 8?

Tags: mysql, database, module, drupal-8

I have a question about drupal 8.
I'm using Drupal 8 with MAMP.
In Drupal 8, the DB(MySQL) interaction is complete.
But I don't know how to show on the homepage.
How can I upload my db information and show up this as a homepage?

I would like to ask you for your excellent advice.

[image: This is my problem]